# Indicating Date_Time format when adding another column with Elapsedtime in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `df` with `Date_Time` column in the following format.

```
Date_Time
01/04/2023 00:00:00
01/04/2023 00:00:01
01/04/2023 00:00:03
01/04/2023 00:00:04
...
03/04/2023 00:00:04
03/04/2023 23:59:00
04/04/2023 00:00:00
```

I am trying to add a new column to the df with `Elapsedtime` incrementing in seconds.
Here is the code I am using:

```
df['Date_Time']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'])
df['deltatime'] = (df['Date_Time'] - df['Date_Time'].shift(1)).astype('timedelta64[s]')
df['deltatime'].iloc[0] = 0 #filling up the first value with 0 instead of Nan
df['Elapsedtime'] = df['deltatime'].cumsum()
```

The problem seems I need to add formatting to the `Date_Time` because the day and month are getting swapped, and see below the output I am getting; the `Elapsedtime` jumps by a month when the date changes from 1st of April to 2nd.

```
    Date_Time       Elapsedtime
0   2023-01-04 00:00:00 0.0
1   2023-01-04 00:00:01 1.0
2   2023-01-04 00:00:02 2.0
3   2023-01-04 00:00:03 3.0
    ...
86339   2023-01-04 23:58:59 86339.0
86340   2023-01-04 23:59:00 86340.0
86341   2023-02-04 00:00:00 2678400.0
86342   2023-02-04 00:00:01 2678401.0
86343   2023-02-04 00:00:02 2678402.0
```

I tried to set `infer_datetime_format=True`, but this didn't help.

Comment: be explicit use `dayfirst=True` or `dayfirst=False` in `to_datetime` depending on the format (D/M/Y or M/D/Y)

Comment: I added dayfirst=True, however it didn't change the output. I am still getting the jump by a month.

Comment: I also tried to add the format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', this seems to work

Comment: glad you solved it, when you have issue with datetime conversion always try to be explicit ;)